# Hungarian salami in carry-on luggage

Tags: schengen, food-and-drink, airport-security, hand-luggage

I'm traveling (by plane) between 2 Schengen countries and want to transport several large big Hungarian Salami sausages in my hand luggage. Do I need to worry of any kind of possible hassle when passing airport security?

Comment: I can't speak to Schengen counties, but my wife and I brought a Hungarian salami back from our honeymoon in Budapest into the United States.  We declared it on return and the customs official has no issues when inspecting our bags.

Comment: How large? How many? Which airports? (As an aside, I really feel like munching on some Hungarian sausage, with either palinka, or perhaps some fine Tokaj. Yum yum.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I traveled with one big (~2ft) salami within EU, and seen people flying from Madrid with pretty big pieces of hamon in the carry-on luggage. Airport security didn't care about this at all.

However in your case it depends whether both countries are also in EU or not (some Schengen countries are non-EU, like Switzerland). If your destination country is not EU, you will have to clear customs on arrival, and it may not allow imports of meat products - check with the destination country, and be ready to declare it to customs.

If both countries are in EU, there are no customs then.